# Selecting Different Web Elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, qwebelement

I am a Software Quality Assurance Engineer and I am trying to create an Automated test for a webpage.

**Some background:**

The framework of Selenium that my company uses ONLY allows you to use X paths saved as an object then you use pre-existing methods like "click (someobject)" or "enter (someobject)" etc.

**Problem:**

I'm currently trying to create a test that selects multiple buttons that are on the same class. There are 6 set buttons that I need to be able to select. Now I can do this but using:

```
`//*[@id="tenant-details-accordion"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a
 //*[@id="tenant-details-accordion"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/a
 //*[@id="tenant-details-accordion"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/a
 //*[@id="tenant-details-accordion"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a
 //*[@id="tenant-details-accordion"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/a
 //*[@id="tenant-details-accordion"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/a`
```

-However this is only **temporary** because the test will fail later down the road when a button is removed... I have talked to the Development team about adding Unique ID's to each button. But it does not seem like that is a path they want to go down...

**Possible Solution:**

- **Is it possible to narrow the ‘scope’ of Selenium?**
  For example telling Selenium to look through a specific class instead of the entire page?
  -My thought is to have it search for a class, match a specific text, then select Set.
- **If yes, then also is it possible to combining multiple X path's**
  Something like....

  `//div[@class='col-sm-4'].... //div[contains(.,'Birth Date: Set +')]`

My thought is that I could create an Xpath that narrows what Selenium will actually be looking through.

1. Searching for the class
2. Searching for Text "Birth Date"
3. Selecting Set Button

**Here are some pictures:**
[image: FRONT END]

Here is some HTML when I inspect the page
[image: HTML CODE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want something like this:

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4'][.//*[contains(text(), 'Birth Date')]]//a
```

Meaning select the link from the `div` that has a `class` with value `col-sm-4` and contains the specified text.

Or it could also work like this:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Birth Date')]/a
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've already asked this and we've answered it.

But here are multiple solutions:

1. `//div[@class='col-sm-4' and contains(text(),'Birth Date')]/div/a`
2. `//div[contains(@class,'col-sm-4') and contains(text(),'Birth Date']//a`

there are many more options. Try and visit w3schools.com to learn more about xpath.

Answer (score 1):

In order to first locate the **div** with class 'col-sm-4' and text as 'Birth Date:' and then find the link with text 'Set +' under it, any of the following XPATHs can be used:

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4' and contains(text(),'Birth Date')]/descendant::a[1]
```

Or

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4' and contains(text(),'Birth Date')]/descendant::a[contains(text(),'Set +')][1]
```

Or

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4' and contains(text(),'Birth Date')]/descendant::a[text()='Set +'][1]
```

Comment: why use descendant instead of `//`?

Comment: Xpath //div[@class='col-sm-4' and contains(text(),'Birth Date')]//a[1] should also work. However, in case, if for some reason it does not work, then descendant can be used to locate the required link.